# How do I select the correct coefficient in this linear combination?

Tags: vectors

there's my doubt:

I'm solving this exercise:

Let $\underline{u}$ and $\underline{v}$ be two orthogonal unit vectors, and $\underline{t}$ the linear combination of $\underline{u}$ and $\underline{v}$ that has an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with $\underline{u}$ and is a unit vector. Tell the coordinates of $\underline{t}$ according to the base $\{\underline{u}$,$\underline{v}\}$.

This is my clue:

$\begin{cases} \underline{t} = \lambda\underline{v} + \mu\underline{v} \\ \underline{t}\cdot\underline{t}=1 \\\underline{t}\cdot\underline{u} = \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$

After some calculations I find this:

$\begin{cases} \underline{t} = \lambda\underline{v} + \mu\underline{v} \\ \lambda^2+\mu^2=1 \\\lambda = \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$

That leads me to the following result:

$\lambda = \frac{1}{2} \\ \mu = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

While my book reports simply the result with positive $\mu$.
Why can't the other one be acceptable? How do I select the correct one?

Comment: And indeed, both solutions are correct. You can see, in the real plane ($\mathbb R^2$), with $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$: both $(\frac12,\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$ and $(\frac12,-\frac{\sqrt3}{2})$ are valid solutions.

Comment: I believe this is about $\mathbb{R}^3$, anyway my book explicitly points out that the negative solution can't be correct (no explaination though...), maybe that's about the fact that the angle between two vectors is influenced by orientation?

Comment: All that without introducing the concept of orientability? And, worse, in $\mathbb R^3$? ("Worse", because obviously if you have the 3rd dimension, what looks "anticlockwise" when looked at from "above" becomes "clockwise" when looked at from "below"...) Is that book by any chance online? I would like to have a peek...

Comment: If you want I can have a picture of it. (that's not in english anyway, so I doubt it would be useful)

Comment: Never mind... The bottom line is - I am as puzzled as you are. If they had any thoughts about orientation, they should've spelled it explicitly, or it can be inferred from the context in the book, or the author was mistaken IMHO.

Comment: @user8734617 If my mind doesn't cheat me when I attended the class the teacher told us to consider the angle between two vectors as the convex angle between the two segments containing the representative of them, attached to a same point, maybe that could be useful?

Comment: I'm not sure how it helps. The angle between $u$ and $t$ is always $60^{\circ}$, the question is whether the angle between $v$ and $t$ will be $30^{\circ}$ or $150^{\circ}$... and all those angles are convex...

Comment: @user8734617 The only thing this book reports about orientation is this:

"It's obvious that defining the angle this way makes it independent from the choice of the point. That requires, instead, the definition of a positive rotation sense. The angle between the two vectors is then considered positive if the rotation that leads the segment containing the first one to override the second one is in the positive sense. Negative otherwise"

Comment: @user8734617 Considering that the exercise required to establish [...] such that $\underline{t}$ had an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with $\underline{u}$ and the only correct solution is the positive one, I'd say that the counterclockwise sense is the one meant as positive (?)

Comment: As long as the $90^{\circ}$ angle from $u$ to $v$ is also counterclockwise... which is *the* condition that is missing from your problem. They should've insisted that (oriented) bases $(u,v)$ and $(u,t)$ represent the same orientation, or something equivalent.

Comment: if that was the case, how do I determine (possibly with calculation) which one of the two solutions is the correct one?

Comment: For two bases, say $(u,v)$ and $(u',v')$ (here $u'=u, v'=t$) write the matrix of $(u',v')$ in the basis $(u,v)$: if $u'=au+bv, v'=cu+dv$, this is the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}$. You say that those two bases have the *same* orientation if $\det A\gt 0$, or the *opposite* orientation if $\det A\lt 0$. ($\det A=ad-bc$)